# Hadoop java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Tags: java, hadoop

The input is a list of house data where each input record contains information about a single house:
(address,city,state,zip,value). The five items in a record is
delimited by the sign comma (,). The output should be the average house value in each zip code. Following is my current code:

```
public class ziphousevalue1 {

    public static class ZipHouseValueMapper extends Mapper < LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable > {
        private static final Text zip = new Text();
        private static final IntWritable value = new IntWritable();

        protected void map(LongWritable offset, Text line, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
            zip.set(tokens[3]);
            value.set(Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]));
            context.write(new Text(zip), value);
        }
    }

    public static class ZipHouseValueReducer extends Reducer < Text, IntWritable, Text, DoubleWritable > {

        private DoubleWritable average = new DoubleWritable();

        protected void reduce(Text zip, Iterable < IntWritable > values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int count = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable value: values) {
                sum += value.get();
                count++;
            }
            average.set(sum / count);
            context.write(zip, average);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: ziphousevalue <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        Job job = new Job(conf, "ziphousevalue");
        job.setJarByClass(ziphousevalue1.class);
        job.setMapperClass(ZipHouseValueMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(ZipHouseValueReducer.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(3);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
        configure(conf);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public static void configure(Configuration conf) {
        System.out.println("Test+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

    }
}
```

However, it produces following error. I have taken a look at similar problem in this site, none seems to solve the problem. I have made sure the input files are correct. Is there something else I should check to fix this error? Thank you for your time.

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at ziphousevalue1$ZipHouseValueMapper.map(ziphousevalue1.java:29)
at ziphousevalue1$ZipHouseValueMapper.map(ziphousevalue1.java:24)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/11/11 22:10:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local112498506_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/11/11 22:10:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/11/11 22:10:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local112498506_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
15/11/11 22:10:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Comment: The exception tells you the exact problem - start debugging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ZipHouseValueMapper.map`, you have:

```
String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
zip.set(tokens[3]);
value.set(Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]));
```

which means `value` has to have at least 5 comma-separated sequences, but `value` is a newly created IntWritable. Will that have at least 5 comma-separated sequences when converted to a `String`? Seems unlikely. You probably want to be doing something with `line` instead.

Comment: I did not realized that. It should be `line.toString().split(",");` Thanks so much. It works now.

Comment: @aguibert I'm trying. the site says I can accept the answer in 3 minutes.

Comment: oh yea, forgot about that restriction =)